# Spring RestController: HTTP 406 when an exception is thrown in Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a RestEnd point which returns ResponseEntity with byte[] payload, that is `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` sample snippet below:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/image/{id}" , produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() {

   // some logic

   byte[] bytes = fetchImageService.getImage(id):
   if(imageFound) {
       return new ResponseEntity<byte[]> (bytes,headers,HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   else {

         throw new ImageNotFoundException(Cannot find file);
   }
}
```

When image is present, it returns ResponseEntity, however when image isn't present, then it throws (NOT returns) Business exception.

In my rest client , I specifically use header "accept: application/octet-stream".

For exception scenarios, i am getting HTTP 406 response from server. I guess this is due to the fact when exception is thrown, it is build as `JSON object` and since PRODUCES is `application/octet-stream`, hence it is incompatible. This is my understanding.

Can anyone suggest is my understanding is correct, and if so, how can I fix this.

Comment: There is no enough info, or, at least, I can't reproduce it. I use spring boot 2.1.3, and get status code 500 with content-type text-html. Have same method signature and annotations as provided in your example. I throw `new Exception()`. Is it possible that there is additional server between client and spring application? If you need just solution, you may set headers manually, without `produce` attribute.

Comment: Ok, I see, got 406. I'm bit confuset, but it look like correct behavior. What you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a handleer for that exception that handles the exception to return the value you want. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) might help

Answer (score 0):

There is your pervertion:

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/image/{id}"} , produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    if (true) {
      response.setStatus(404);
      response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
      response.flushBuffer();

      throw new Exception();
    } else {

      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  }
```